# Khafka consumer reading with junk value from event hub

Tags: apache-kafka, azure-eventhub

I am reading byte array content from event hub using consumer and I have a junk value followed by count of items(byte arrays) and then the byte array fetched .
Eg value [-95 , 4 , 50,48,50,48]
I want this junk -95 to be removed , is it kafka issue or event hub issue.
If so how to resolve it kindly need help

Answer (score 0):

Your consumers receive whatever is sent to Event Hubs. Event Hubs never changes the payload in an EventData and relays it as is. Thus, if you are seeing some content which looks like changed from the consumer's perspective, I strongly recommend you to check the senders and make sure they send correct payload.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , Yeah checked the payload from sender it does not have junks , I read in azure portal as they usually send events through amqp AND amqp CANNOT deserialize bytes COMPLETELY leading TO junk CHARACTERS,.

Comment: AMQP is a binary transport protocol. It won't do any sort of serialization or deserialization. Can you try receiving events with a simple console app and see if they arrive corrupted? You can use code snippets from here - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-hubs/get-started-dotnet-standard-send-v2#receive-events

Comment: Thanks , will check and reply back